# Vagrant, lucid32, postgres: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vagrant

When I try:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I don't have problems when I

```
vagrant@lucid32:/sudo su - postgres
postgres@lucid32:/ psql
postgres# (can list databases)
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
# Vagrant uses 33.33.33.10 like addresses
host    all         all         33.33.33.0/24         trust
```

Comment: Maybe you are using the same username and password in `database.yml` as for the postgres server on your machine? If so, you must instead [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html](create a user for the database). It’s common to have a separate user for each application/database.

Comment: The error message says the auth method is `ident` but all method entries in pg_hba.conf are set to `trust`, so `ident` shouldn't even be attempted. Inside psql, try `show hba_file;` to make sure that you're looking at the right pg_hba.conf file.

Comment: @Buck for whatever reason, I can only install postgres 8.4 on lucid32...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you tried to restart PostgreSQL and you are still getting that error that is not your whole pg_hba.conf.

Some distros have an extra line above the table which sets postgres to ident.  Search for the string of postgres and correct the line that shows up.